# How can I create a directive that will be adding to page a list of other directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Lets say I have a list of directives that I already wrote:

```
my-directive1
my-directive2
....
```

Now, I am creating a new directive that will get a list of directives (my-directive1, my directive2, ...) and I want its template to be able to create them and add each one of them to the page.

Can I do that? Will it work?

Comment: It should work out of the box, unless you're injecting a template. Then you'll need to use `$compile`

Comment: What the $compile will do?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/mgtrkg

Comment: 10x, I see it works with templates, but what if I want to render directive? will it work the same?